# Problem importing images into iMovie 10

Tags: mac, high-sierra, graphics, imovie, import

I've recently encountered an issue importing images into iMovie 10 on some of our computers. The machines are running High Sierra and iMovie 10.1.6.

On effected units, some imported images appear as a black box with a small portion of the image appearing in the upper left corner of the box. On other  (apparently identical) machines, the same image imports with no issues.

The problem occurs in all user accounts on the effected machines, even a newly created user, so preference or Movie Library issues seem to be ruled out. The only fix that has worked so far was a full OS and iMovie reinstall.

Has anyone else encountered this? If so, were you able to find the cause?

Example:

[image: the problem]

EDIT: upgrading to Mojave does solves the issue, but this is not a practical solution in our situation

Comment: Welcome to Ask Different? Could you post some images to help describe your problem better. Thanks

Comment: Image added. You can see the full image in the timeline, but when played only a fraction of the image displays.

Comment: To add to the question, upgrading to Mojave does solves the issue, but this is not a practical solution in our situation.

Comment: If you this a bug then upgrading is one of the only solutions

Comment: Yes. I've come to the conclusion that it is a bug. I was just surprised that there were not more folks reporting the same issue. Upgrading is the only solution that I have found that works. We have 300 plus machines and try to keep them on the same system for the school year, so upgrading is inconvenient, but that's what we are going to do.